# Clearing input fields with React

Tags: javascript, html, dom, reactjs

I am confused about why I cannot clear `<input>` field values using this simple pattern with React:

```
onComponentDidMount: function () {
    this.clearFields();
},

clearFields: function () {
    document.getElementById('username_field').value = '';
    document.getElementById('password_field').value = '';
},
```

I don't think it's a problem with React, I think there some other issue at hand but I am not sure what's going on. But the fields definitely do not clear out. Later on, I can call this.clearFields() and that function does work as expected, but not when the component first mounts.

Answer (score 2):

The correct React lifecycle function is called `componentDidMount`, not `onComponentDidMount`

However, you don't want to do it this way if the inputs are also rendered with React. It's usually better and more relevant to the application to change values stored in the state, and let the render function deal with setting the value of the input fields.

Comment: agreed you should be doing this in getInitialState, and this.setState({});
when it comes to react